# Scrolling an item to the top position is not working in RecyclerView for few items in the adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to scroll a specific item to the top in RecyclerView.

Here is the code I am using,

```
rvTweets.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
```

or

```
linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(postion,0);
```

Both the code work when RecycelerView has enough items to cover the complete height of the screen. Otherwise, it does not scroll the desired position to the top.

Comment: Yes RecyclerView scroll happens only when there are more items right?If there are less items and if they can fit in one screen obviously scroll doesn't happen.

Comment: So, what is the solution?

Comment: you can do a trik @user2970035 move that item to top of your arraylist as suggest my below ans